# How to use ng-if with async data

Tags: angularjs

My **ng-if** is **always** false. Makes sense as the data I'm using in my controller is provided via an API response. My question is, how do I use ng-if with async data?

My HTML below:

```
  <div>
    <span ng-if="isFollowed">
      <form ng-submit="unfollow()">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Unfollow">    
      </form>
    </span>

    <span ng-if="!isFollowed">
      <form ng-submit="follow()">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Follow">    
      </form>
    </span>
  </div>
```

My controller code:

```
$http.get('/api/isFollowing', {params: { fromID: fromID, toID: toID }})
    .then(function(res){
        if(res.message === true){
            $scope.isFollowed = true;
        }else {
            $scope.isFollowed = false;
        }
    });
```

By the way, I know my **/api/isFollowing** API call works as when I check the response in the browser, it comes back as **true**.

I thought the **.then** would do the trick but I am obviously mistaken. Might be a question frequently asked but I am not seeing the answer anywhere.

Using Angular 1.6.4 by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to access the data property of your response and check whether the message property of data is a boolean value. Change your controller code like this

```
$http.get('/api/isFollowing', {params: { fromID: fromID, toID: toID }})
    .then(function(res){
        if(res.data.message === true){
            $scope.isFollowed = res.data.message;
        }else {
            $scope.isFollowed = !!res.data.message;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Checking mate - brb

Comment: `$scope.isFollowed = res.data.message` will be better.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot Vivz!

Comment: @alexmac I have updated but does the op have a boolean message property. ?

Comment: @ShayanKhan Great. Glad to be of help. Please mark as answer if it helped. :)

Comment: Can't for the next few minutes - SO thinks I'm a bot :)

Comment: @Vivz according the code, client expects that value is a boolean, otherwise double negation could be used (it converts any value to boolean): `$scope.isFollowed = !!res.data.message`